# Why is the sorted array being printed when no return statement from function is used and without using a global variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, return

I'm reading up on sort algorithms and came across this code:

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        mid = len(arr)//2
        L = arr[:mid]
        R = arr[mid:]
        mergeSort(L)  # Sorting the first half
        mergeSort(R)  # Sorting the second half

        i = j = k = 0
    
        # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] 
        while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
            if L[i] < R[j]:
                arr[k] = L[i] 
                i+= 1
            else: 
                arr[k] = R[j] 
                j+= 1
                k+= 1
    
        # Checking if any element was left 
        while i < len(L): 
            arr[k] = L[i] 
            i+= 1
            k+= 1
    
        while j < len(R): 
            arr[k] = R[j] 
            j+= 1
            k+= 1

# Code to print the list 
def printList(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        print(arr[i], end =" ")
    print() 

# driver code to test the above code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    #arr = [12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7]
    arr = [38, 27, 43, 3, 9, 82, 10]
    print ("Given array is", end ="\n") 
    printList(arr) 

    mergeSort(arr) 
    print("Sorted array is: ", end ="\n") 
    printList(arr)
```

This code is contributed by Mayank Khanna.

The array `arr` is not global or no return statement has been used in `mergeSort()`, why does it print the sorted array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: `arr` is passed to `mergeSort` which modifies it.